# #2002 - — The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured)

Tags: mysql, websocket, xampp, wamp, server-configuration

I am using UniServer Zero XIII 13.3.2. Everything was working correctly for me a few hours ago. I just made my PC sleep and I guess something suddenly broke the MySQL sockets or connections because next time I started the computer and tried to connect, I received this error:

```
#2002 -  — The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).
```

I tried restarting the computer and starting/stopping Apache and MySQL multiple times. In theory, MySQL is starting successfully because I see green squares, not red:

[image]

Nonetheless, when I go to the MySQL Console, I see this:

```
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061)

C:\Users\[path]\UniformServer13_3_2_ZeroXIII\UniServerZ\core\mysql\bin>
```

Also, when I go to http://localhost:90/us_opt1/index.php, I see this:

```
Welcome to phpMyAdmin

Error
MySQL said: Documentation

#2002 -  — The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).
 mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No se puede establecer una conexi�n ya que el equipo de destino deneg� expresamente dicha conexi�n.
 Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
 mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No se puede establecer una conexi�n ya que el equipo de destino deneg� expresamente dicha conexi�n.
Retry to connect
```

Clearly, the MySQL connection was not successful even though apparently I can stop and start MySQL successfully from what I see in the UniServer Zero XIII panel. Any ideas about what broke the MySQL connection or environment and how to fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what went wrong but what I did was to download again UniServer Zero XIII 13.3.2 from https://sourceforge.net/projects/miniserver/files/Uniform%20Server%20ZeroXIII/13_3_2_ZeroXIII/ and both Apache and MySQL were up and running, working correctly again from this new installation. Of course then I had to move source code to this new folder location where I completed the installation. I wanted to share this workaround instead of trying to figure out what happened, which I have no idea as I mentioned at the beginning of this answer.